# There is something wrong with my Python code involve the replace function

Tags: python

I was creating a function about replacing multiple part of a string with multiple number but for some reason, the output is not what i expected.

```
from pyprimes import isprime
def prime_replace(x, l = []):
    lst = []
    string = str(x)
    for n in range(10):
        for i in l:
            string = string.replace(string[i], str(n))
        lst.append(int(string))
    return lst 

print prime_replace(x = 56243, l = [2, 3])
```

The output of this function is a list [56003, 56113, 56223, 56333, 56444, 56555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999] but what i wanted is [56003, 56113, 56223, 56333, 56443, 56553, 56663, 56773, 56883, 56993] Can someone help me with this and tell me what went wrong, thank you.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the original string, and `replace` is replacing "all occurrences"

Here's part of a print out for how it's generating the output you see:

```
...
string is now 56333
replacing 3 with 3
string is now 56333
replacing 3 with 4
string is now 56444
...
```

You can see that we successfully got `56333` like you wanted, but then you wanted to replace `str[2]` (actual value: `3`) with `str(n)` (actual value: `4`), which replaced *all* occurrences of `3`

One workaround for this specific scenario is to make a copy of your string:

```
def prime_replace(x, l = []):
    lst = []
    string = str(x)
    for n in range(10):
        newstr = string
        for i in l:
            newstr = newstr.replace(string[i], str(n))
        lst.append(int(newstr))
    return lst 

print prime_replace(x = 56243, l = [2, 3])
```

Output:

```
[56003, 56113, 56223, 56333, 56443, 56553, 56663, 56773, 56883, 56993]
```

#### [Demo (not recommended)](http://ideone.com/yNhKt7)

However, [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) may not be the best choice since it will replace all occurrences of the "oldstring" with the "newstring". It looks like what you're really trying to do is to change `string` at indices in `l` to be the next value in `range(10)`, we can do this through indexing and appending:

```
def prime_replace(x, l = []):
    lst = []
    string = str(x)
    for n in range(10):
        newstr = string
        for i in l:
            newstr = newstr[0:i]+str(n)+newstr[i+1:];
        lst.append(int(newstr))
    return lst
```

### [Demo (better)](http://ideone.com/ylUZJU)

Answer (score 0):

string.replace(a,b) replaces all instances of a with b. so, '56243'.replace(3,0) evaluates to '56240'. You are trying to replace the values at the indicies in l, so you should replace

```
string = string.replace(string[i], str(n))
```

with

```
string = string[:i] + str(n) + string[i+1:]
```

The other answer fails on cases where the value at an index to be replaced is repeated elsewhere in the number, i.e. `prime_replace(562432,[2,3])`

Answer (score 0):

I have also found another solution for it by turning the string into list

```
from pyprimes import isprime
def prime_replace(x, l):
    lst = []
    string_lst = list(str(x))
    for n in range(10):
        for i in l:
            string_lst[i] = str(n)
        lst.append(int("".join(string_lst)))
    return lst 

print prime_replace(56243, [2, 3])
```

Output

```
[56003, 56113, 56223, 56333, 56443, 56553, 56663, 56773, 56883, 56993]
```

But thank you very much for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You really want a mutable data-structure here to simplify your logic. You can get what is essentially a mutable string by using a `bytearray`. So here is an alternative approach:

```
In [11]: def prime_replace(x, l=None):
    ...:     if l is None:
    ...:         l = [] # careful with mutable default arguments
    ...:     lst = []
    ...:     string = bytearray(str(x), encoding='ascii')
    ...:     for n in b'0123456789':
    ...:         for i in l:
    ...:             string[i] = n
    ...:         lst.append(int(string))
    ...:     return lst
    ...:

In [12]: prime_replace(x = 56243, l = [2, 3])
Out[12]: [56003, 56113, 56223, 56333, 56443, 56553, 56663, 56773, 56883, 56993]
```

Also, [**be careful with mutable default arguments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

I use a `bytearray` because I think it simplifies things more. A list also works. But note with `bytearray` and by iterating directly over the ascii `b'012345679'` it simplifies everything by a lot, and you don't have to keep converting things back-and-forth between `str` and `int`